# Scheduling using Application.OnTime

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make a program that runs in a loop in the background and operates on refreshable query without hanging Excel at the same time and when something wrong happens it displays a message.

I scheduled a procedure with Application.Ontime - function tells itself when to run again and it stops when I toggle a slider in Excel Worksheet.

Why is this MsgBox showing twice every time? First message tells it is (Now) time and second right after tells it is (Now+20) time.

```vb
Public Sub sendingAmessage(schTime As Date)
   
If Worksheets("MAIN").Range("ToggleText").Value = "MONITORING ON" Then
    
    AppActivate Application.Caption
    MsgBox (schTime)
    
    Application.OnTime schTime, "'sendingAmessage""" & DateAdd("s", 20, Now) & "'"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Because you are scheduling it to run at `schTime` which is not relative to when you close the MsgBox.

Comment: The line of code that schedules runs after closing MsgBox, so as a parameter I pass the Now + 20 sec. Macro stops on MsgBox, so it must be relative.

Comment: Note that VBA does not support multi-threadding. Your title is a bit unclear. • Further I highly recommend to use `If … Else … End If` instead of using `Goto` which is a bad practice.

Comment: I did it because I can't End Sub in If block. I can set a global boolean flag and turn it on in first IF, check it in second one OR make the function return a boolean value. But that is not my case.

Comment: *I did it because I can't End Sub in If block.* That should be `Exit Sub`.

Comment: This is so embarassing, thank you.

Comment: Surely you don't need the first IF block at all - if Monitoring is On it will do the second block, if it's not on (i.e second block is not true) then it won't do anything anyway.

Comment: Changed it. Thank you for pointing this out. I think I left it because of reasons I don't remember.

Comment: `so as a parameter I pass the Now + 20 sec` - what you pass to the *next* `sendingAmessage` is relative to when you close the MsgBox in the *current* `sendingAmessage`. So in each `sendingAmessage` the time of the next run is relative to the time the MsgBox was closed in its previous life, not in the current.

Comment: You are right. The problem is I close msgBox ASAP and on 2nd loop it appears twice. One right after another at the same time. First one with "Now" time and next one with "Now+20". Like it is compeletly ignoring that msgBox stops macro execution. I don't see it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of how to re-schedule or have a recurring OnTime Event. Just see when you call a procedure you need to recall the OnTime sub from the procedure.

```
Public RunWhen As Double
Public Const cRunIntervalSeconds = 1
Public Const cRunWhat = "TheSub"  ' the name of the procedure to run
Public Password As String


' See top of Module to see public Variable and Constants
Sub StartTimer()
    RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, cRunIntervalSeconds)
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, _
        Schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub TheSub()
    ' Set Cell A1 to the Current Time
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = Time
    StartTimer  ' Reschedule the procedure
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, _
        Schedule:=False
End Sub
```

If you also want to try out the windows API method see below:
Just note that sometimes trying to cancel this is finicky. If it does save everything first and then if you close out of the workbook a process outside excel in the os will kill(forceclose) excel, as well if you call the wrong procedure as mentioned below.

```
' Windows Timer functions via Windows API
' PtrSafe needed for API to work
' LongPtr is safe versions for 64 and 32 bit systems
' It converts between Long and LongLong types accordingly
' Note when an incorrect pointer is listed excel will likely crash
' If error External Error-Handlers will look to OS for help and kill excel.exe

Option Explicit
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetTimer Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal HWnd As LongPtr, _
    ByVal nIDEvent As LongPtr, _
    ByVal uElapse As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpTimerFunc As LongPtr) As Long

Public Declare PtrSafe Function KillTimer Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal HWnd As LongPtr, _
    ByVal nIDEvent As LongPtr) As Long

Public TimerID As Long
Public TimerSeconds As Single
Public bTimerEnabled As Boolean
Public iCounter As Single
Public bComplete As Boolean

Public EventType As Integer

Sub StartTimer()
    iCounter = 2
    TimerID = SetTimer(0&, 0&, iCounter * 1000&, AddressOf TimerProc)
End Sub

Sub EndTimer()
    KillTimer 0&, TimerID
    bTimerEnabled = False
    bComplete = True
End Sub

Sub TimerProc(ByVal HWnd As LongPtr, ByVal uMsg As LongPtr, _
    ByVal nIDEvent As LongPtr, ByVal dwTimer As LongPtr)
    Dim rc As Double

    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print iCounter
    ' Continue
    If iCounter <= 60 Then
        rc = On_Time.Range("F1045000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        On_Time.Range("F" & rc) = Time
        ThisWorkbook.Save
    End If
    
    ' EndTimer
    If iCounter > 60 Then
        EndTimer
    End If

    iCounter = iCounter + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: You may want to consider using Windows Task Scheduler. Just a thought. https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10

Comment: Yeah, good idea. If you have admin rights you can schedule a macro to be ran using Task Scheduler.